# Display document library metadata in Dynamics CRM 2016 using Server-based SharePoint integration

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using SharePoint 2013 and displaying document library in Dynamics CRM 2016.

I am using "Server-based SharePoint integration" and I see all the out of the box columns in the CRM.

How can I display additional metadata in the CRM?